# how can print data from database in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql, pdo

i want to print date column from database in javascript code

this is the original javascript code i want to change date countdown

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#countdown').countdown('2017/07/10 06:32:11', function(event) {
 $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
 });

});                                
</script>
```

and this code after edit :

```
<?php
$count = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `auction` WHER ORDER BY id DESC");
$count->execute();  
foreach ($count->fetchAll() as $rowL)    
{
?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var countdw;
  countdw = = <?php echo $rowL['dateauction']; ?> 
 $('#countdown').countdown(document.write(countdw), function(event) {
$(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
});

});                                
</script>
<?php   
} 
?>
```

Comment: Are you wanting only `#countdown` to have this or different ids?? What is the end goal? Right now you have a loop that only acts on this one id, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: Plus, you should not write the javascript in a loop like you have it, that is just a bunch of repetition. You could just create a `json` object and iterate through that object in js. Also, it appears you only need to select `dateauction`, no point in selecting `*`. You probably don't need `WHERE` either.

Comment: sorry i forget this code in php : <div id="countdown"></div>

i want to get time column from database and show in countdown id

Comment: @Rasclatt when i write the time directly in countdown work fine but after get from database he is not work

Comment: Yes but are you expecting multiple rows or just one value from the database?

Comment: multiple rows from the database

Comment: i dont have problem about sql code i want to get row['dateauction'] from database and print in javascript code 

here :  $('#countdown').countdown(document.write(countdw), function(event)

because countdw dont work that my problem

Comment: Yes but ids are meant to be unique so you are writing a bunch of the similar script for the same id on the page, which doesn't make any sense. Why are you trying to write  scripts to the same id so many times?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one value from the database, you don't need to loop anything, although I can't imagine you have one whole table dedicated to one row unless you have a bunch of rows chronicled, in which case you probably should limit to one row to return. At any rate, it's likely it should look something more like this:

```
<?php
# You probably just need to limit 1 and only select the column you need
$query = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT `dateauction` FROM `auction` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$query->execute();
# Just fetch without a loop
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // You should probably have quotes and a semicolon, also only one equal sign
    var countdw = '<?php echo $row['dateauction'] ?>';
    $('#countdown').countdown(document.write(countdw), function(event) {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
    });
});                                
</script>
```

Comment: i dont have problem about sql code i want to get row['dateauction'] from database and print in javascript code 

here :  $('#countdown').countdown(document.write(countdw), function(event)

because countdw dont work that my problem